# StringCharcaterIterator is not saving the characters to characters array or List<E>

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, character

I am trying to iterate through a string and save the characters in a character array. It iterates perfectly and prints the characters but when I try to save the characters in the **Array** or in a **List**, it gives me **NullPointerException.** Can anyone point out the mistake I am doing here?

```
try {

                    List<String> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Rehan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Marks\\build\\classes\\marks\\input.txt"));
                    List<Character> marksC = null;                     
                    for(String line : result ){
                      System.out.println(line);
                      //Reversing each line of string                        
                      StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder(line);
                      sb.reverse();
                      String RS = sb.toString();
                      System.out.println(RS);
                      //To read first sequence of integers in reversed string                            
                      StringCharacterIterator si = new StringCharacterIterator(RS, 0);
                        for(int i = 0; i <= RS.length() ; i++){
                            while (si.current()!=' '){
                                char c = si.current();
                                marksC.add(c); //This line giving NullPointerException
                                System.out.println(c);
                                si.next();
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

    }
```

Comment: You should initialize `marksC` via `marksC = new ArrayList<Character>();`

Comment: Thank you, i got it right.  Now, how to use character array instead of a list?

Comment: If you do not know the length of the array that will be trouble. Bu if you know, you can create it via `Character [] charArr = new Character [length];`

Comment: No I donot know the length, it will be variable in each iteration of loop.

Comment: So you should continue to use `marksC = new ArrayList<Character>()` if you do not know the length of the array.